# Access denied when creating symlinks

Tags: windows-7, windows, command-line, symbolic-link

One of the development tools we use (ember-cli.com) requires symlinks in order to be performant on windows. The recommended strategy is to either run your shell as an admin or to add the `SeCreateSymbolicLinkPrivilege` privilege to your user. My issue is that neither of these things seem to be working for me and `ember-cli` continues to use the slow non-symlink path.

As part of its startup process `ember-cli` tests for the ability to create symlinks by creating a `tmp` file, while watching the file system activity using procmon I see the following:

`6:01:19.2258921 PM   node.exe      8576   FileSystemControl       C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Temp\canLinkDest.tmp   ACCESS DENIED Control: FSCTL_SET_REPARSE_POINT`

This to me indicates *something* is causing weirdness, however I'm not sure how to diagnose what exactly is causing the issue.

It might be worthwhile pointing out that this is happening on my office workstation on which I have admin rights, but which is also running all manner of enterprise protection stuff e.g. virus scanners, rights managements software etc...

#### more log detail

`6:01:19.2255745 PM   node.exe      8576   CreateFile    C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Temp\canLinkDest.tmp       SUCCESS       Desired Access: Write Attributes, Delete, Synchronize, Disposition: Create, Options: Synchronous IO Non-Alert, Non-Directory File, Open Reparse Point, Attributes: N, ShareMode: None, AllocationSize: 0, Impersonating: AD\username, OpenResult: Created
6:01:19.2258921 PM   node.exe      8576   FileSystemControl       C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Temp\canLinkDest.tmp   ACCESS DENIED Control: FSCTL_SET_REPARSE_POINT
6:01:19.2259123 PM   node.exe      8576   SetDispositionInformationFile       C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Temp\canLinkDest.tmp   SUCCESS       Delete: True
6:01:19.2259465 PM   node.exe      8576   CloseFile     C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Temp\canLinkDest.tmp       SUCCESS

6:01:19.2289415 PM   node.exe      8576   CreateFile    C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Temp\canLinkSrc.tmp       SUCCESS       Desired Access: Read Attributes, Write Attributes, Delete, Synchronize, Disposition: Open, Options: Synchronous IO Non-Alert, Open Reparse Point, Attributes: n/a, ShareMode: Read, Write, Delete, AllocationSize: n/a, Impersonating: AD\username, OpenResult: Opened`

Comment: Is the target of the symlink local or remote? What does `fsutil behavior query symlinkevaluation` (at an elevated cmd prompt) return?

Comment: @dxiv Local to local symbolics are enabled.

Comment: @dxiv I'm also pretty sure this is local to local.

Comment: Then I'd try to create a symlink manually next, using `mklink.exe` at the cmd prompt. Maybe it gives a more meaningful error message, or at least a better chance at google'ing the issue outside the `ember-cli` context.

Comment: @dxiv i can create links using mklink, it only seems to be a problem when running this through ember-cli/node.js

Comment: It's not obvious from the procmon log, but maybe you can tell from elsewhere (logfile etc) what's the target of the symink that fails to create, and whether that one is valid and accessible. Other than that, sorry, it looks  like an `ember-cli` specific issue at this point, and I have no experience with that.

Comment: Have you checked your permissions on `C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Temp` ?